# Next js flickering/flashing on conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use localstorage for persisting auth with next js and using conditional rendering to wait till localstorage is accessible but upon rendering the empty page and loading new content/page everything flickers/flashes and can't find a suitable solution to use localstorage without compromising user experience

current code is simple

```
useEffect(() => {
    new Promise(res => res(getToken())).then(res => {
        if (res !== null) { router.replace('/dashboard'); }
        else { setToken(false); }
    })
}, []);

    <>
    {
        token !== null &&
        <div>page content</div>
    }
    </>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setVal(localStorage.getItem('token'))

 }, [])
const [val, setVal] = useState(null)
return (
    <>
        {
            val ? <div>Hello from About</div> : <p>loading...</p>
        }
    </>
)
```